# How can I see incoming changesets using hg4idea?

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea

When using IntelliJ with Subversion, there is a view called "Incoming" that lets me see incoming changesets from the remote repository. With the Mercurial command line, there is an equivalent command `hg in`. I like this command because I can see what's coming before pulling it. This view seems to be missing from the IntelliJ-Mercurial integration; my "Changes" window only has one tab called "Changes." Is there a view for this somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of IntelliJ IDEA 11.0, it's still not possible to see "incoming" or "repository" changes with either mercurial or git repositories the way you can with subversion ones.

If you look at the online help for IDEA 11.0 http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/local-committed-and-incoming-changes.html you'll see a specific note:

"Repository and incoming changes are not supported by Git and Mercurial integrations."

There is an open issue in the IDEA bug tracker http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-73130 reported in August 2011 but without any apparent plans for a fix.